# url rewrite with .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I have an URL like:

`http://www.mysite.nl/vakantiehuizen/Denemarken/Bornholm`

I want to rewrite it for SEO purposes:

`http://www.mysite.nl/vakantiehuizen/denemarken/bornholm`

I have tried all possible methods like:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

but fails every time and gives 500 internal server error...

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a `RewriteMap` inside of an htaccess file. It can only be declared in vhost or server config. The other two lines you can use in an htaccess file.

Comment: Thanx for your answer .. would you like to tell what should i do to edit server config @jon Lin

Comment: See this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18670/how-to-redirect-any-url-to-lowercase-url